Serialize header parameter as json instead of using toString() with openapi-generator-maven-plugin
I am trying to use the openapi-generator-maven-plugin java generator to serialize a complex object as JSON instead of serializing the object using the toString.
I can't figure out how to make the java generate a client that will serialize the header object as json.
The object I want to pass in my header :
@Data
public class RequestContextDTO {
  @Valid
  private TrackingDTO tracking;
}

@Data
public class TrackingDTO {
  private String trackingNumber;
}

YAML :
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Test Header Serialization
  version: "1"
servers:
- url: http://localhost:8080
  description: Generated server url
paths:
  /test/:
    get:
      tags:
      - MyController
      summary: Test Header As Complex Object
      operationId: postRequestWithHeader
      parameters:
      - name: x-request-context
        in: header
        description: Request context
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/RequestContextDTO"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
components:
  schemas:
    RequestContextDTO:
      required:
      - businessContext
      - userInfo
      type: object
      properties:
        tracking:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/TrackingDTO"
    TrackingDTO:
      required:
      - trackingNumber
      type: object
      properties:
        trackingNumber:
          type: string

I want to generate a "java" client from my yaml file in order to call my new API.
I am using the following plugin to do so :
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.8.0</version>
                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>/definitions/newApi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>

                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <library>jersey3</library>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <apiPackage>${client.package}.api</apiPackage>
                                <invokerPackage>${client.package}.api</invokerPackage>
                                <modelPackage>${client.package}.model</modelPackage>
                                <performBeanValidation>false</performBeanValidation>
                                <serializationLibrary>jackson</serializationLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

The "openapi-generator-maven-plugin" will generate the following code :
public class MyControllerApi {
  private ApiClient apiClient;
  
  public ApiResponse<Void> postRequestWithHeaderWithHttpInfo(RequestContextDTO xRequestContext) throws ApiException {
    if (xRequestContext == null) {
      throw new ApiException(400, "Missing the required parameter 'xRequestContext' when calling postRequestWithHeader");
    } else {
      Map<String, String> localVarHeaderParams = new LinkedHashMap();
      localVarHeaderParams.put("x-request-context", this.apiClient.parameterToString(xRequestContext));
      String localVarAccept = this.apiClient.selectHeaderAccept(new String[0]);
      String localVarContentType = this.apiClient.selectHeaderContentType(new String[0]);
      return this.apiClient.invokeAPI("MyControllerApi.postRequestWithHeader", "/test/", "GET", new ArrayList(), (Object)null, localVarHeaderParams, new LinkedHashMap(), new LinkedHashMap(), localVarAccept, localVarContentType, (String[])null, (GenericType)null, false);
    }
  }
}


ApiClient. generated method :
  public String parameterToString(Object param) {
    if (param == null) {
      return "";
    } else if (param instanceof Date) {
      return formatDate((Date) param);
    } else if (param instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
      return formatOffsetDateTime((OffsetDateTime) param);
    } else if (param instanceof Collection<?>) {
      StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
      for(Object o : (Collection<?>)param) {
        if(b.length() > 0) {
          b.append(',');
        }
        b.append(String.valueOf(o));
      }
      return b.toString();
    } else {
      return String.valueOf(param);
    }
  }

The code above will call the xRequestContextDTO.toString() method instead of serializing the object as json like my yaml says.
Is there a way to tell the maven plugin to generate a java client that will serialize the header complex object as json  ?  Maybe i miss something in the yaml or in the maven plugin configuration.

Architecture team realized it was not a good practice so the need for this is not there anymore...
